# Undefined method for nil:NilClass Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot

I have a rails 4 application that uses sunspot. Here's my controller:

```
before_action :set_product_type

def index
   if params[:search].present?
      @search = Product.search do
         fulltext params[:search]
         with(:product_type_id, @product_type.id)
      end
      @products = @search.results
   else
      @products = Product.all.where(:product_type_id => @product_type.id)
   end
end

private
def set_product_type
  @product_type = Product_type.find(params[:product_type_id])
end
```

and here's my model:

```
searchable do
  text :data
  integer :product_type_id
end
```

when I use this, I get:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

but when I make the with use a static value:

```
with(:product_type_id, 3)
```

it works fine.

I thought it might be because the @product_type.id was null, but when I print out `@product_type.id` it is set to a value.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Exactly where in `index` did you check that the `@product_type.id` value isn't `nil`?

Comment: @mbratch, on the index.html.haml, I just put this on the page: `%h1=@product_type.id` and it printed out 3 (which was the id for that collection)

Answer (score 0):

It's because Your @product_type instance variable was never defined (at least I don't see it in index action, it may also be defined if before_filter), so it's nil.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry I forgot to post, but I set @product_type in a `before_action`

Comment: Obviously something is flawed there, otherwise You wouldn't be getting nil. COuld You update You question with code from there ?

Comment: Jekabasons, sure I just posted it.

Comment: Are You sure that this  Product_type.find(params[:product_type_id]) actually finds anything ? Output @product_type in Your index action.

BTW, why so weird name for a model - Product_type? It's a well defined pattern to use camelcase for Ruby classes.

Comment: When I output `@product_type.id` in the index action I get an id back, so its not nil...I was following a tutorial on Railscast which is where I got the name of the model.